# Communication between 2 arduino boards

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, communication, analogwrite

I am not really 100% too sure how to do this but I am trying to make my arduino UNO communicate with my arduino MEGA. The reason why I needed to do this was because I was using the RFID module along with a TFT display and the problem I faced is that on the arduino mega they both needed pin 53. Luckily I have an arduino UNO so I just went for that instead for the display. I am trying to use the `analogWrite()` function to send analog signals from my MEGA over to the UNO so that the TFT display on the UNO can display the results. The UNO would also read the analog inputs coming from the MEGA. This did not work very well. The analog inputs are being sent from the MEGA but the UNO is not reciving them. I am using a PWN pin on the MEGA to send the analog output to the UNO.

This diagram shows what I mean:

[image]

These are the 2 compotents I am using:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqXdB.png
TFT display

[image]

RFID

[image]

This shows how the libary sets out the pins. I am only a beginner so I personally don't want to mess around with the libary.

Comment: Use Serial or I2C or SPI. Never try this sort of thing with analogue, it's just not realistic.

Comment: How do you use those? I am quite new to all of this.

Comment: Start by googling for some tutorials. There's no shortage.

Comment: What was the deal with pin 53?  What were they using it for?  Sounds like SPI in which case they can just share it.  Perhaps figuring that out first would be smarter and you won’t end up with such a convoluted design.  If it’s not about SPI then most likely you can switch one of them to

Comment: Also note that a PWM signal is alternating 5V and ground.  It isn’t a true analog signal.  When you try to read it with the other Arduino you won’t get an analog reading.  You’ll get 0 sometimes and 5V sometimes.

Comment: @Delta_G pin 53 is used for an RFID module

Comment: @Delta_G Do you know at all how you can send analog signals on an arduino because there is a `analogWrite()` function

Comment: Pin 53 is just the default Slave Select pin for SPI. You can pick literally any pin instead of 53. There's nothing special about it (unless you're doing SPI slave mode).

Comment: @Majenko I think the RFID module uses SPI. The issue is that I have a display which uses SPI and an RFID module that uses SPI and they both cannot use it at the same time.

Comment: Yes they can. That's the whole point of SPI. The only pin that needs to be unique is the SS pin, All the others can be shared. And you can change pin 53 for *any other pin*

Comment: I have what modules I am using above:

Comment: If you have "shields" that mount on top of the Arduino then cut pin 53 off the top level one and solder a wire from there to another pin somewhere else. If you don't have "shields" then just plug the slave select pin from one of the modules into a different pin.

Comment: @Majenko I don't have the tools to do that!

Comment: Then get the tools. Those are basic tools for working with electronics. Arduino isn't LEGO®, it's electronics. Real electronics.

Comment: Take the wire that connects to pin 53 of the RFID module and plug it into another hole on the Arduino. Look at the number next to that hole. Read the manual for the RFID library you are using and look for the words "chip select" or "constructor" or "slave select" and it will tell you where to stick the number you just read.

Comment: @Majenko, I don't have sheilds, I think the RFID documentation specifically mentions that pin 53 needs to be used and additionally this is the same for the TFT display

Comment: @Majenko The picture above shows what I mean

Comment: The RFID neither knows nor cares what pin it's using. Only the library cares, and most of those have a specific way of telling it what pin *you* want to use. RTFM for the library, not the RFID.

Comment: @Majenko I am only a beginner so I personally don't want to mess around with the library.

Comment: I'm not telling you to "mess around" with the library. I am telling you to read the manual. Or at the very least *tell us what library you are using so we can point you to the paragraph that tells you how to use a different SS pin*!

Comment: @Majenko Here is the libary: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid

Comment: You see in the table of pins on that page you link to? See the little `[2]` next to pin 53? Click it. It takes you to a bit that says "Configurable, typically defined as SS_PIN in sketch/program."

Comment: All the examples have `#define SS_PIN ...` in them where you can change the pin that you want to use instead of 53. The constructor has `MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN)` where you can put any pin numbers you like (or just redefine the macros to be something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the I2C interface.

TX:

```
// Wire Master Writer
// by Nicholas Zambetti <http://www.zambetti.com>

// Demonstrates use of the Wire library
// Writes data to an I2C/TWI slave device
// Refer to the "Wire Slave Receiver" example for use with this

// Created 29 March 2006

// This example code is in the public domain.


#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
}

byte x = 0;

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(8); // transmit to device #8
  Wire.write("x is ");        // sends five bytes
  Wire.write(x);              // sends one byte
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting

  x++;
  delay(500);
}
```

RX:

```
// Wire Slave Receiver
// by Nicholas Zambetti <http://www.zambetti.com>

// Demonstrates use of the Wire library
// Receives data as an I2C/TWI slave device
// Refer to the "Wire Master Writer" example for use with this

// Created 29 March 2006

// This example code is in the public domain.


#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
}
```

Schematic:

[image: Image by Dronebot Workshop; check out their tutorial for more info: https://dronebotworkshop.com/i2c-arduino-arduino/]

Image by Dronebot Workshop; check out their tutorial for more info: https://dronebotworkshop.com/i2c-arduino-arduino/

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: What is the address 8 part?

Comment: That is just any address both the boards communicate on. It can be any number but it has to be the same on both sides.

Comment: Isn't the RX pin pin 0 and the TX pin is pin 1 thought or vice versa?

Comment: Can you show a schematic that shows this? It might help me to get a better understanding.

Comment: Yes so this is the wire library can doesn't use the Serial put. I will put the schematic in the answer.

Comment: Can it work with different boards? I am using an arduino MEGA and an arduino UNO

Comment: Yes, for the mega, right next to the Serial pins, there is an SDA and SCL pins. Use those. Also, remember to connect both of their grounds together, or else it will NOT work.

Comment: Have you potentially got a schematic using a mega and uno? (I am quite new to the arduino)

Comment: I put the schematic in the answer.

Comment: What if you want only 1 way communication

Comment: This is one way. One is TX and the other is RX.

Answer (score 1):

Pin 53 is just the default "slave select" pin. There is nothing special about it. You can use any other pin as slave select, as long as the libraries for your devices allow it (check the documentation and tutorials for those libraries).

You cannot transmit information with `analogWrite()` since it isn't really analogue (it's PWM), and analogue doesn't have enough definition for reliably representing more than a handful of discrete values anyway.

Comment: I realize I'm later here, but: As an AVR SPI master, you cannot allow your SS pin to go low as input.  So if you chose something other than 53 (or SS on an AVR generally) to be your slave select line, you'd still want to set 53 to be OUTPUT, or INPUT_PULLUP, or INPUT and pulled up externally.  Otherwise you may be taken out of master mode by noise on the pin.  Not that it goes against your main point, but here is still one thing to be aware of that is special about 53/SS with regard to SPI master.